# Store Shapely STRtree to a file for reuse

Tags: python, shapely

I have an incredible amount of shapely geometry polygons, saved in a shapefile. I load them into a shapely STRTree. It seems very inefficient to have to recalculate their envelope every time the program is ran. Is there a way (with pickle maybe?) to store the entire tree? Even storing them with Redis would be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**On second thought...** pickling for this reason will not really help much, because essentially all pickling the strtree does is convert each *individual geometry* to wkb format and write them all to a single file (see comment [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1033#issuecomment-730658499)). Unpickling recreates these geometries from the wkb and then creates a new `STRtree` with them. So the boundaries will be calculated again either way.

---

Pickling appears to work, though I have not tested it on all geometry types.

```py
import pickle

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

polys = [Polygon(((i, i), (i + 1, i), (i, i + 1))) for i in range(100)]
strtree = STRtree(polys)

with open('strtree.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(strtree, f)
```

And then in another process

```py
import pickle

from shapely.geometry import Point

with open('strtree.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    strtree = pickle.load(f)

print(strtree.nearest(Point(39.8, 39.8)).wkt)
# POLYGON ((40 40, 41 40, 40 41, 40 40))
```

There was [an update](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/pull/915) in `shapely==1.7.1` that avoided a segfault when unpickling some `STRtree` objects. So you may want to get on the latest version for this.